# ssh tunnel using MobaXterm to raspberry pi connected to a wn3000rp wifi extender

Tags: ssh, debian, raspberry-pi, ssh-tunnel

I would like to connect to my raspberry pi using a MobaXterm to play with it from any computer, here how I started to make that work... I try to connect via MobaXterm using windows 8. My windows and my raspberry are both connected on a wifi network using the same netgear wn3000rp, it's a wifi extender.

When i create a ssh tunnel to my raspberry MobaXterm ask me to login to the raspberry, it process and then i receive this answer :

```
 Connection refused
```

thank for your answer

Comment: Did you try local tunnel?

Comment: you have to install ruby on debian and then run the command . search for local tunnel here on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your port is being used. 
If you don't have lsof already you can download and install it by becoming root and running:

```
root@machine:~# apt-get install lsof
```

To discover the process name, ID (pid), and other details you need to run:

```
lsof -i :port
```

So to see which process is listening upon port 24 we can run:

```
root@machine:~# lsof -i :24
```

After this you should be able to move on towards a solution.